# Listview of Music

Tags: android, media

I developed a music player that read one file on server and i want to add list of music(Read file from internal storage (not sd card)) and play them, this is my code of list; but when i test it in my emulator, return force stop with no error and in Android monitor and when I test it in my phone, app run for 2 seconds and finish activity (i add permission External Storage in manifest) ....(music player activity is a seperate activity and work correctly but list activity not added music to list view)
this is my code :

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity {
private static  final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(List.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(List.this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(List.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(List.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{
        doStuff();
    }
}

private void doStuff() {
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    getMusic();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_list,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}

public void getMusic(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver =getContentResolver();
    Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri,null,null,null,null);
    if(songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

        do{
            String currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
            String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);
            arrayList.add(currentTitle+"\n"+currentArtist);
        }while (songCursor.moveToNext());
    }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String[] permissions,  int[] grantResults) {
   switch (requestCode){
       case REQUEST_CODE:{
           if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(List.this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                   Toast.makeText(this,"permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   doStuff();
               }
           }else{
               Toast.makeText(this,"No permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               finish();
           }
           return;
       }

   }
}
```

}

Comment: You can add directly to an ArrayAdapter. You don't need an Arraylist by the way